# Way to use typehints to distinguish coordinate frames using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, mypy, typing

I'm working on a python library dealing with coordinates in different frames. As I had quite some issues with confused frames, I'd like to bring more order into my code.

For this purpose, I want to assign typehints to coordinates and use Mypy to check them. My current approach is

```
from typing import NewType, cast
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

frameA = NewType('frameA', npt.NDArray)
frameB = NewType('frameB', npt.NDArray)

def f(x_A : frameA) -> frameB:
    # do something to get from frame A to frameB
    x_B = - x_A
    return cast(frameB, x_B)

# should work
x_A : frameA = np.random.rand(3,2)
x_B = f(x_A)

# should throw error
x_B : frameB = np.random.rand(3,2)
x_A = f(x_B)
```

Indeed, Mypy is able to detect if the input of `f` is in the correct coordinate frame. What bothers my however, is that the definition `x_A : frameA = np.random.rand(3,2)` throws an error as well, because `np.random.rand(3,2)` is of type `ndarray[Any, dtype[floating[_64Bit]]]` and to make it `frameA`, I have to cast it.

Is there any nicer way to do this without the need of casting the variables every time I generate new ones? F.e., It would be really nice to have something like

```
x_A : frameA = np.random.rand((3,2), type=frameA)
```

Answer (score 2):

`frameA` is not just an alias for `NDArray`; it is an entirely distinct type whose values are *created from* (albeit trivially*) values of type `NDArray`.

You need to write

```
x_A : frameA = frameA(np.random.rand(3,2))
```

Like any other combinations of types, Python will not simply cast or otherwise construct a value of type `frame` implicitly just because it's *possible* to convert the value returned by `np.random.rand(3, 2)`.

---

* At runtime, `frameA` really does simply return the value of its argument unchanged, so in that sense `frameA` and `NDArray` values share the same runtime representation.